# How can I retrieve a full list of account activities with the Dynamics CRM Views?

Tags: dynamics-crm

Using the CRM views, is there a way to retrieve a list of all of the activities linked to a specific account?

I want it to retrieve not only those associated with the account directly, but also those associated with the account's contacts, cases, etc. I am trying to replicate the list generated when you click the Activities option from within an account.

So far I have retrieved the contacts for the account and their activities. I also noticed that CRM doesn't seem to always return what I expect. Sometimes activities related to contacts of the account are not displayed. Other times, emails / appointments that are logically related to the account but have nothing in their regardingobjectid field are shown.

I am hoping this doesn't mean creating the mother of all joins or querying each activity type separately. Particularly because I need all of the related case activities, opportunity activities, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used something like this.  Effectively I build a table var with all the guids of the items I want to search (in my case accounts and contacts) then I query AcitivtyParty for all activities where they are a party on the activity - then over to Activity to get the details.

```
Declare @account_guid varchar(200)
Select @account_guid = 'insert some guid here'

Declare @GUIDS as Table(id varchar(200), fullname varchar(200), objecttype char(2)) 
Declare @ActivityIds as Table(id varchar(200))

--grab all guids we need activities for
    Insert Into @GUIDS
    Select contactid, fullname, 'C'
    From FilteredContact
    Where accountid = @account_guid
    UNION ALL
    Select accountid, [name], 'A'
    From FilteredAccount
    Where accountid = @account_guid 

--find all activities where the account/contact are referred to
Insert Into @ActivityIds
Select activityid
From FilteredActivityParty fap
Join @GUIDS g on g.id=fap.partyid
Group By activityid

Select *
From FilteredActivityPointer fap
Join @ActivityIds a on fap.activityid = a.id
Where statecode<>2 --hide canceled items
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use Rollup request (if you're working using SDK web-service) to accomplish your task:

> Rollup Action
>   Microsoft Dynamics CRM has a powerful Rollup message that lets you open an entity 
>   instance, such as an account, and find information not only about the account's related 
>   records (opportunities, quotes, orders, invoices, contracts, and cases), but also about 
>   the account's subaccounts and the contacts' related records.

more:

> TargetRollupActivityPointerByAccount Class (CrmService)
>   Specifies the parameters needed to retrieve all activities related to the specified 
>   account.

Answer (score 0):

check out the post below, it use a retrieve plugin to rollup activities for a custom entity, which is not supported by out-of-box CRM: 
http://www.catapulterp.com/blog/2013/03/11/rolling-up-custom-entities-in-microsoftcrm-2011-and-crm-online/